# Golang select doesn't enter `default` case

Tags: go

I have the following Go code. When I execute it, it doesn't enter the default case, but instead loops forever. Can anyone see why this is happening?

Thanks

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
    ch1 := make(chan int, 50)
    ch2 := make(chan int, 50)

    wg.Add(2)
    go func() {

        for {
            select {
            case i := <-ch1:
                fmt.Println("Channel 1: ", i)
            case j := <-ch2:
                fmt.Println("Channel 2: ", j)
            default:
                fmt.Println("Hello")
                break
            }
        }

        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        ch1 <- 42
        close(ch1)

        ch2 <- 27
        close(ch2)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: [Receive Operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator): _"A receive operation on a closed channel can always proceed immediately"_. You also have an [ineffective `break`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements) in the `select`, where I assume you meant to break form the `for` loop.

Comment: @JimB Many thanks, mate! I have just started to learn Go and its specification page makes me really confused and uncomfortable.

Comment: You may want to bookmark ["Channel Axioms" by Dave Cheney](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
    ch1 := make(chan int, 50)
    ch2 := make(chan int, 50)

    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case i, ok := <-ch1:
                if !ok {
                    break
                }
                fmt.Println("Channel 1: ", i)
                wg.Done()
            case j, ok := <-ch2:
                if !ok {
                    break
                }
                fmt.Println("Channel 2: ", j)
                wg.Done()
            default:
                fmt.Println("Hello")
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        ch1 <- 42
        close(ch1)

        ch2 <- 27
        close(ch2)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I added a 1 second sleep before `ch1 <- 42`; this will help to run the `for` loop a couple of times before the channel sends `42`.  I moved the wg.Done() calls into the cases, and also added an `ok` result to the case tests to check for channel closure.

Once ch1 is closed, for example, the `i, ok := <-ch1:` case will be false, because `ok` will be false.  If the channel is instead not closed yet, `ok` will be true, so the case will execute, run the fmt.Println(), and decrement the wait group counter.

The same will happen in the ch2 case.

So the issues you ran into are:

1. wg.Done() is not invoked, because it is outside an infinite loop.
2. The loop was infinite because there was no check for whether the channel is closed or not. A receive on a closed channel does not block, and a receive on a closed channel also returns the zero value for the channel's type, so both i and j will be `0` after the close() statements execute on their respective channels.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helps me alot :D

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to reach the default case you can do it using this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int, 50)
    ch2 := make(chan int, 50)

    go func() {
        ch1 <- 42
        close(ch1)

        ch2 <- 27
        close(ch2)
    }()

    select {
    case i := <-ch1:
        fmt.Println("Channel 1: ", i)
    case j := <-ch2:
        fmt.Println("Channel 2: ", j)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Hello")
    }
}
```

the reason why the default case get printed is because the goroutines don’t get enough time to produce the output

Comment: This creates the opposite problem though; the sending goroutine doesn't have enough time to run before the select{} executes and the process exits.